# JavaFX Graphic freezes, kind of

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

My ListView is not scrollable and I cant select anything else in the window. Normally when you hover a Button it changes colour, but not even that happens. Clicking the Button works though.

I really dont know how I can fix this, please help!

The ListView stays slected(Blue border) but I cant scroll

[image]

My Code:

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project 
Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package hue1_fx_client;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
* FXML Controller class
*
* @author Benjamin Kesetovic
*/
public class Window_statistikController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private PieChart piechart;
@FXML
private ListView<String> listview;

private Map<Integer, String[]> log = new HashMap<>();
private String[] arr;
private int richtig = 0;

private ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData;

ObservableList<String> ol = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
@FXML
private Button btn;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 *
 * @param url
 * @param rb
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    log = Business_logic.getLog();

    listview.setItems(ol);
    listview.setCellFactory((ListView<String> ListView) -> new ListCell<String>() {
        //Wenn ein neues Element @text zur Listview hinzugefuegt wird 
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String text, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(text, empty);

            if (text == null || text.equals("")) {
                setText("");
                setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgray;");
            } else {
                if (text.charAt(0) == '+') {
                    setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
                    setText(text.substring(1));
                } else {
                    setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
                    setText(text);
                }
            }

        }

    });

    //Einen leerstring hinzufügen um die Hintergrundfarbe lightgray zu setzen
    ol.add("");
    //Wieder entfernen
    ol.remove(0);

    //ObservableList füllen
    for (int i : log.keySet()) {
        arr = log.get(i);
        if (arr[1].equals("ok")) {
            ol.add("+" + arr[0] + " -> " + arr[2]);
            richtig++;
        } else {
            ol.add(arr[0] + " -> " + arr[2] + " [" + arr[1] + "]");
        }
    }

    pieChartData
            = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new PieChart.Data("Richtig", richtig),
                    new PieChart.Data("Falsch", (log.size() - richtig)));

    //Piechart mit Daten füllen
    piechart.setData(pieChartData);
    //Legende verstecken
    piechart.legendVisibleProperty().setValue(false);

    //Richtige Seite grün einfärben
    pieChartData.get(0).getNode().setStyle(
            "-fx-pie-color: green;"
    );
    //Falsche Seite rot einfärben
    pieChartData.get(1).getNode().setStyle(
            "-fx-pie-color: red;"
    );
    piechart.setTitle("Vokabel Prüfung");

    //Neu starten des Programmes um neu anzufangen
    btn.setOnAction((event) -> {
        try {
            Hue1_fx_client.getKlasse().close_stage();
            new Hue1_fx_client().start(new Stage());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Window_IOerrorController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    });
}
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="759.0"         xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"     fx:controller="hue1_fx_client.Window_statistikController">
<children>
  <PieChart fx:id="piechart" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="60.0"     prefHeight="280.0" prefWidth="280.0" />
  <ListView fx:id="listview" layoutX="308.0" layoutY="23.0" prefHeight="371.0" prefWidth="444.0" style="-fx-font-size: 18; -fx-font-weight: bold;" />
  <Label layoutX="308.0" layoutY="-2.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="444.0" style="-fx-alignment: center; -fx-background-color: lightgray;" text="{Vokabel} -&gt; {Eingabe} [Lösung]">
     <font>
        <Font size="15.0" />
     </font></Label>
  <Button fx:id="btn" layoutX="122.0" layoutY="361.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Nochmal" />
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Post your FXML.

Comment: I added the fxml

Answer (score -1):

An insight to your code would be helpful...

but try `setfocusable(true)`for the ListView object.

Comment: It seems to me that setfocusable doesnt exist for a listview, at least not in FX